# FirebasePerformance Crash on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-performance

Our app is crashing randomly after using FirebasePerformance here is a stack trace

```
CoreFoundation 0x208166b6 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 292

1   APP_NAME 0x0084e037 -[FPRNetworkTrace checkpointState:] + 312
2   APP_NAME 0x0084e2eb -[FPRNetworkTrace didCompleteRequestWithResponse:error:] + 264
3   APP_NAME 0x0085000b __InstrumentURLSessionTaskDidCompleteWithError_block_invoke + 220
4   CFNetwork 0x20ee9505 __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke170 + 74
5   Foundation 0x21111679 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 6
6   Foundation 0x210725f3 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 144
7   Foundation 0x21064bc9 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 766
8   Foundation 0x21113931 __NSOQSchedule_f + 190
9   libdispatch.dylib 0x2047a423 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1756
10  libdispatch.dylib 0x20479a61 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 282
11  libdispatch.dylib 0x2047c15d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 394
12  libdispatch.dylib 0x2047bfcd _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x20631b29 _pthread_wqthread + 1022
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x20631718 start_wqthread + 6
```

Comment: As stated in crash report, It is crashing while setting object in mutableDictionary. Please post relevant code.

Comment: But the stack trace shows that this is a call by [FPRNetworkTrace checkpointState], so the code is relevant, and at least I found 2 others with the same exact issue after adding FirebasePerformance

Comment: Hello, I'm one of the authors of the SDK. Basically, the code here looks like this:

`aDictionary[@(<an enum>).stringValue] = @(<timeIntervalSinceEpoch>);`

It's valid for the value to be nil, but not the key. I'm not sure how the stringValue of an NSNumber of an enum could ever be nil. Are you positive the crash isn't in another thread? Can we see the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?

Comment: I sent @mike_haney a couple of stack traces, but never found a solution, we ended up removing Firebase Performance from our iOS app as it's a no go with these random crashes, just kept it for Android.

Comment: I reached out to @Shehabix letting him know that these crashes *may* have been fixed in the most recent release (6 days ago). I haven't heard back from him, but I have heard back from other users about these issues in recent days. Would anyone else be willing to confirm they still occur in the latest release? You can also PM me at haneym@ or message in the #performance channel of the firebase slack at https://firebase.community

Comment: @mike_haney we haven't gone through a regression test cycle yet, I'll update you once we do full app regression test

Comment: Sweet, thanks for your help!